# Is one git remote aware of another?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have a local repository, to which I have associated two remotes (via git remote add...). I regularly push to both remotes. Are the two remotes linked or aware of each other in any way?

In case it's relevant, I'm trying to design a homework "competition" for multiple people to work on without being aware of the others' work.

Comment: I'm not sure how your use case is related to your question. In your "homework competition", wouldn't a bunch of different people share a *single* remote? In this case, they will absolutely be aware of each other's work.

Comment: Possibly? I don't think your local git repository has a good way of tracking that. You could compare the commits between the two master branches and if they contain duplicates, assume they're related.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson That doesn't really make any sense. "Duplicate commits" are impossible, and not really related to having multiple remotes.

Comment: Yes, it does. Any time you copy ("clone") a repository, you're going to get the same commits.

Comment: I was thinking each person would then be given the address of one unique remote (thus all competitors would start at the same starting point), which they can then clone and modify at will.

Comment: *"Are the two remotes linked or aware of each other in any way?"* -- Why is your local repository aware of the remote repositories? Because you added them as *remotes* into the local repository. The same thing happens with all Git repositories. On creation, a Git repository either does not have any remote (if it was created by `git init`) or it has one remote (if it was create by `git clone`). More remotes can be added later.

Comment: @EM_IE The remote doesn't need to be unique, because when the people in question clone the repository, they'll get a new copy of it. The best way to manage such a scenario is for each person to create a new branch (if you want to separate their changes, but still compete, as you put it).

Comment: As an added note, you can have students/competitors add each other as remotes, if this makes sense to you.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson That sounds like a cleaner approach, but I wanted to avoid the possibility of one person looking at another's branch. But maybe that's overkill...

Comment: @EM_IE You could use private (via a web service of some sort) remote repositories for each person, so that people cannot see each others' code.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Yeah that's what I was thinking: formulate the assignment on my local, and spawn a bunch of private remotes from it, then give each person one remote to work on. Thanks.

Comment: Why not have each person simply create a Github account, and [duplicate the project](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) under their own account? The kind of thing you're trying to achieve is solved constantly in the Git world. Each clone is a complete copy of the entire project, once a user has cloned your repo they can create a new remote wherever they like.

Comment: @meagar Also a good point. I didn't know GitHub allowed private forks. Thanks.

Comment: @EM_IE It doesn't, I stealthy edited my comment to replace "fork" with "duplicate". You wouldn't be able to have a public project and still let people create private forks, but you could have a *private* project and invite the students to it.

Comment: @meagar Sneaky :) I will look into all of these suggestions - they're very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not. You can have an arbitrary number of remotes, and none of them are inherently made aware of each other because of this.

Answer (score 3):

The two remote are "links" on your own repository but do not know anything about each other.

So if you are working on your own repo and push your changes to one of the remote, the other remote does not know about these changes until you push them to this one as well.

Git is a distributed system and remote are just normal repositories on other ones machine (well, if they are bare then they are not usual repositories but still repositories). The remotes do not know about your local repository so they dont know about your other remotes as well.

Answer (score 2):

Each repo has its own remotes. The only way one repo can be aware of another is if you add the second repo as a remote to the first. This is a one-way relationship. If repo A is a remote of repo B, then B does not automatically know anything about A.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to repos as remotes of the same local repo does not make them aware of each other. So unless you've added one as a remote on the other remote, there's no relationship between them.